# JPEG EOI nonexistent in Android ICS 4.0.1

Tags: android, jpeg, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I've got a simple jpeg validator that checks the final two bytes of uploaded images for the standard EOI indicator (0xFF,0xD9).

I've noticed images uploaded from ICS 4.0.1 no longer have this EOI marker.

Have others noticed this strangeness?

Answer (score 1):

Android is completely screwed up in regards of coding jpeg's. If you investigate closer you'll see that it probably also misses a JFIF header and that the EXIF data is corrupt.

File a bug report.